# 2 overloads have similar conversions

Tags: c++

A similar question to this 
[C++ Function Overloading Similar Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950840/c-function-overloading-similar-conversions)
has been asked and i understand the general premise of the problem. Looking for a solution.

I have 2 overloaded functions:

```
virtual IDataStoreNode* OpenNode(const char *Name, bool bCreateIfNotExist,int debug=0) { return 0; 
}

virtual IDataStoreNode* OpenNode(const char* Name,int debug=0) const { return 0; }
```

From the errors it would appear that bool and int cannot be used to distinguish function overloads.

The question is , is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I suspect that your problem will go away if you get rid of the evil default parameters.

Comment: I need to read somemore about evil default parameters , but if you are changing an interface, they do come in handy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`bool` and `int` *can* be used to distinguish function overloads. As one would expect, `bool` arguments will prefer `bool` overloads and `int` arguments - `int` overloads.

Judging by the error message (I assume that the title of your question is a part of the error message you got), what you are dealing with is the situation when the argument you supply is neither `bool` nor `int`, yet conversions to `bool` and `int` exist and have the same rank.

For example, consider this

```
void foo(bool);
void foo(int);

int main() {
  foo(0);     // OK
  foo(false); // OK
  foo(0u);    // ERROR: ambiguous
}
```

The first two calls will resolve successfully and in expected manner. The third call will not resolve, because the argument type is actually `unsigned int`, which however supports implicit conversions to both `bool` and `int` thus making the call ambiguous.

How are you calling your functions? Show us the arguments you are trying to pass.

Answer (score 5):

For the following functions:

```
virtual IDataStoreNode* OpenNode(const char *Name, bool bCreateIfNotExist,int debug=0) { return 0; }
virtual IDataStoreNode* OpenNode(const char* Name, int debug=0) const { return 0; }
```

The following call (as an example, there might be others) would be ambiguous:

```
unsigned int val = 0; //could be double, float
OpenNode("", val);
```

Since a `unsigned int` can be converted to both `bool` and `int`, there is ambiguity. The easiest way to resolve it is to cast the parameter to the type of the parameter in your preferred overload:

```
OpenNode("", (bool)val);
```

OR

```
OpenNode("", (int)val);
```