# VS 2010 : 2 overloads have similar conversions

Tags: c++, overloading

I don't understand what happens here

```
class A{};
class B : A {};

void func(A&, bool){}
void func(B&, double){}

int main(void)
{
    B b;
    A a;
    bool bo;
    double d;

    func(b, bo);
}
```

When compiling, Visual 2010 gives me this error on line `func(b, bo);`

```
2 overloads have similar conversions
could be 'void func(B &,double)'
or       'void func(A &,bool)'
while trying to match the argument list '(B, bool)'
```

I don't understand why the bool parameter isn't enough to resolve the overload.
I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723112/2-overloads-have-similar-conversions), and as pointed in the accepted answer, bool should prefer the bool overload. In my case, I see that first parameter isn't enough to choose the good function, but why the second parameter doesn't solve the ambiguity?

Comment: Weird, esp since the implicit conversion is restricted (private inheritance).

Comment: It's not that the first parameter isn't enough to choose the the good function; it's that the first parameter chooses the second function, and the second parameter chooses the first function. So neither one is chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload resolution rules are even more complicated than Pete Becker wrote.
For each overload of `f`, the compiler counts not only the number of parameters for which conversion is required, but the rank of conversion.

**Rank 1**

> No conversions required
>
> Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
>
> Array-to-pointer conversion
>
> Function-to-pointer conversion
>
> Qualification conversion

**Rank 2**

> Integral promotions
>
> Floating point promotions

**Rank 3**

> Integral conversions
>
> Floating point conversions
>
> Floating-integral conversions
>
> Pointer conversions
>
> Pointer to member conversions
>
> Boolean conversions

Assuming that all candidates are non-template functions, a function wins if and only if it has a parameter which rank is better than the rank of the same parameter in other candidates and the ranks for the other parameters are not worse.

Now let's have a look at the OP case.

- `func(A&, bool)`: conversion B&->A& (rank 3) for the 1st parameter,
  exact match (rank 1) for the 2nd parameter.
- `func(B&, double)`: exact match (rank 1) for the 1st parameter, conversion `bool->double` (rank 3) for the 2nd parameter.

Conclusion: noone wins.

Comment: Well, yes, I left out details for the benefit of beginners. <g>

Answer (score 5):

The overloading rules are a bit more complicated than you might guess. You look at each argument separately and pick the best match **for that argument**. Then if there is exactly one overload that provides the best match for every argument, that's the one that's called. In the example, the best match for the first argument is the second version of `func`, because it requires only a conversion of `B` to `B&`; the other version of `func` requires converting `B` to `B&` and then `B&` to `A&`. For the second argument, the first version of `func` is the best match, because it requires no conversions. The first version has the best match for the second argument, but it does not have the best match for the first argument, so it is not considered. Similarly, the second version has the best match for the first argument, but it does not have the best match for the second argument, so it is not considered. Now there are no versions of `func` left, and the call fails.

Comment: +1 clear and concise, except that the statement *"it requires only a conversion of B to B&"* is not correct. I don't think it is a *conversion*.

Comment: Also, *"requires converting B to B& and then B& to A&"* doesn't make sense. Note that C++ doesn't allow chained-conversion (such as X to Y to Z).

Comment: @Nawaz - the standard's discussion of overloading includes the identity" conversion, which, as I just found out, is the "conversion" that's applied for `B` to `B&`, although it's also listed as "no conversion".

Comment: @Nawaz - the standard does allow chained conversions. There are limits on the number of user-defined conversions in a conversion sequence, but there is no restriction to only one conversion. For example, with a class with an operatorB&, the user-defined conversion to B& could be applied, followed by a conversion of B& to A& (which in a more complicated inheritance hierarchy might not be a no-op). In fact, the rules for choosing an overloaded function are written in terms of "conversion sequences".