# C ++ function matching (priority of built-in conversion and class type conversion)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have this code :

```
class A
{
  public:
   operator int() const
   {
     return 100;
   }
   int operator+ ( int a)
   {
     return 10 + a;
   } 
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  int b = a + 11.5;
}
```

In this code the compiler told me that calling "+" is ambiguous, but there are only two ways of calling `+` I think:

1. use class type conversion, convert object `a` to `int` type
2. Convert `11.5` to type `int`, then use the class `operator+`

I think the priority of the second case is higher than the first one, but why is there ambiguity?

Comment: GCC issues the following warning (but it compiles): `warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second`. Thus, this is ambiguous because standard says so (I don't know where it says so though, so I'd rather not answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS 2010 : 2 overloads have similar conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095205/vs-2010-2-overloads-have-similar-conversions)

Comment: #1 is worse on the first argument, requiring a user-defined conversion (followed by floating point promotion). #2 is worse on the second argument, requiring a floating-integral conversion. Since neither overload is strictly better than the other, the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution to this problem. To match overloaded functions, it is necessary to match every parameter without disadvantage, and at least one of them is in an advantage, and the first and the second can not be used to compare the advantages and disadvantages