# Error: "2 overloads have similar conversions"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

***EDIT:*** As I was writing the question I noticed that the method `std::string GetNodeValue(const std::string& nodePath, const char * defaultValue)` wasn't const. As *LogicStuff* also mentioned in his comment, adding the `const` qualification resolved the ambiguity.

I know this question was already been asked and answered properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723112/2-overloads-have-similar-conversions) and several other times. I understand the underlying problem but I can't quite figure out why it is happening in this particular case and it has awoken my curious self.

I have the following class:

```
class ConfigurationReader
{
public:
    // ...   
    std::string GetNodeValue(const std::string& nodePath, const char * defaultValue)
    {
        const std::string temp(defaultValue);
        return GetNodeValue(nodePath, temp); 
    }    

    template <typename T> T GetNodeValue(const std::string & nodePath, T defaultValue) const 
    {
        boost::optional<T> nodeValue = configuration.getNodeValueNothrow<T>(nodePath);
        if ( nodeValue ) 
        {
            return *nodeValue;
        }
        LogConfigurationProblemsCri(logger, "Node not found: " << nodePath << ", Default value: " << defaultValue);
        return defaultValue;
    }
    // ...    
};
```

The template method has also several specializations for the types `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, and so on up to `uint64_t`.

It works like a charm when used:

```
string someValue = configurationReaderPtr->GetNodeValue("some_noe", "");
uint32_t otherValue = configurationReaderPtr->GetNodeValue("other_node", 11000);
bool yetAnother = configurationReaderPtr->GetNodeValue("other_node", true);
```

Except in one case:

```
uint32_t otherValue = configurationReaderPtr->GetNodeValue("other_node", 0);
```

The error I keep getting is:
"2 overloads have similar conversions
could be '*std::string ConfigurationReader::GetNodeValue(const std::string &,const char* *)' or '*uint32_t ConfigurationReader::GetNodeValue(const std::string &,uint32_t) const*'"

I tried casting the "default" value: `uint32_t(0)`, `static_cast<uint32_t>(0)`, `0U` without any luck.

I should point out that I already found a **workaround**:

```
uint32_t otherValue = 0;
otherValue = configurationReaderPtr->GetNodeValue("other_node", otherValue);
```

But this doesn't answer my curiosity. I am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express and boost 1.54 libraries.

Any thoughts?

Comment: One of the standard headers contains `#define NULL   0`. So the compiler is quite right to consider `0` as a null pointer.

Comment: I've made both overloads equally `const`-qualified and that resolved the ambiguity. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72df7eab48ebb4a4). Not sure how, though.

Comment: An alternative is to get rid of your `const char*` specialization, and use `std::string` as the template type for strings instead.

Comment: @LogicStuff Thank you, it was indeed that. I'm new to SO, but I can't make a comment the "accepted answer". Care to provide one with what you suggested so I can accept yours?

Comment: @Nacho Figured it out, so now it can be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both overloads are considered equally viable for

```
configurationReaderPtr->GetNodeValue("other_node", 0);
```

because:

1. requires an implicit conversion from `0`, which is of type `int` to `const char *`.
2. requires an implicit conversion from `ConfigurationReader*` to `ConfigurationReader const*` (to call `const`-qualified member function)

After making both overloads (equally) `const`-qualified, the code compiles (the function template is preferred). The 1st overload also does not modify any members in the first place.

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72df7eab48ebb4a4)

Answer (score 2):

This is, because 0 is the literal for an empty pointer (which in modern C++ is replaced by "nullptr").

So 0 can be either an int or an empty pointer, especially a char*

Edit to add some reference:
You can find this in the standard as

> 4.10 Pointer conversions 
>   A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t

(the last one is the reference to `nullptr`)

Answer (score -1):

In your particular example, it seems prudent to change signature of string version to

```
std::string GetNodeValue(const std::string& nodePath, const std::string defaultValue)
```

This will remove any ambiguity.

Comment: That case is considered within the template itself. It is required that the signature remains `std::string GetNodeValue(const std::string& nodePath, const char * defaultValue)`